# How to install Sun Java JRE (or JDK) on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, java

I've followed a variety of instructions about modifying my sources.list trying to install Sun's JRE for Java 6 with no luck.  The defining error I'm getting appears to be `package sun-java6-jdk is virtual`.

How do I install sun-java6-jre on Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 3):

The java6 package was moved from the multiverse to the partner repository for Ubuntu 10.04 (and perhaps going forward, for Ubunto 10.10)

Add the repository to your sources.list:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
```

Update the source list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install java

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
```

The above three steps can also be performed in the gui:

1. System --> Administration --> Software Sources
2. Open the `Other Software` tab
3. Click `+ Add...`
4. Enter `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner`
5. Click `+Add Source` to accept the new repository
6. Click `Close` to update the source list
7. Open Firefox and open the following URLs:

   - apt:sun-java6-jre
   - apt:sun-java6-plugin
   - apt:sun-java6-fonts

Alternately, if you want to develop in java, you would install the sun-java6-jdk package.

If you have multiple versions of java installed, you may need to change the default version with the `sudo update-alternatives --config java` command, selecting the one with `j2re1.6-sun` in it.